# Editing multiple files simultaneously with vim/gedit

Tags: debian, ubuntu, vim, editors, gedit

I'm trying to save some work by editing multiple files with the same name located in different directories:

```
$ mkdir -p directory_{0..10}/results
```

How may I create files with the same name in all directories. For example,

```
$ vim/kwrite directory_*/results/output.txt
```

Comment: are you trying to open them for editing or just create them? What you have there will work for editing with vim if the files exist: `vim directory_*/results/output.txt`

Comment: I would also like to edit them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it with your second command. You did it correctly with the first, just use the same shell sequence expansion:

```
vim directory_{0..10}/results/output.txt
```

You should see something in the shell about opening 11 files. Then you can use vim to iterate through each one.